# ASP.NET MVC: Cannot access static Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, static-methods

I have created a class called `Utils` in my controllers Folder. However its static methods cannot be found and accessed. Here is the declaration:

```
using ProjectManager.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System.Web.Security;

        namespace ProjectManager.Controllers
        {
            public static class Utils
            {
                public static bool isInRole(IPrincipal User, string roleName, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var currentUser = (from user in dbContext.Users
                                           where user.Id == User.Identity.GetUserId()
                                           select user).First();
                        RolePrincipal r = (RolePrincipal)User;
                        string[] rolesArray = r.GetRoles();
                        if (rolesArray.Contains(roleName))
                            return true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried referencing the methods using fully qualified name `ProjectManager.Controllers.Utils.isInRole` ?

Comment: It would be helpful to know where/how you are trying to access this method. The method declaration looks correct, so your issue is most likely one of a missing reference or a similar namespace hiding your static class.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you want to use it, VSB, you will need to add:

```
using ProjectManager.Controllers;
```

To the top of the class, or:

```
@using ProjectManager.Models
```

In your Razor view.

Edit: And as @Martin Staufcik very nicely points out, it can be added to your View folder web.config's namespaces section to be accessible across the Views in that folder without having to have an @using in each view.

You will still have to add a using for each back-end class, though.

Answer (score 1):

If the class is used on multiple pages, add the namespace to your web.config in the Views folder:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="ProjectManager.Controllers" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```